# SaveChanges on Many to Many relationship fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here is my base :

And that it contains one movie (IDs comes from an external REST API) :

```
Movie movie = Movie.CreateMovie(999, "MyFirstMovie");
movie.Kinds.Add(Kind.Create(123,"Adventure"));
movie.Kinds.Add(Kind.Create(124,"Comic"));
movie.Actors.Add(Person.Create(321,"John Wayne"));
movie.Directors.Add(Person.Create(120,"John Woo"));
_context.AddToMovies(movie);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Now, when I'm trying to insert a new movie, I got often an exception that said that I'm inserting an entity that already exists in the base.

Suppose I got another "Adventure" movie  :

```
// Here all data comes from an external source and have no control over it.
using(Stream stream = myExternalStream)
{
   Movie movie = Unserialize(stream);
   _context.AddToMovies(movie);
}
// throws the exception because the kind "Adventure" already exists
_context.SaveChanges();
```

How can I avoid this exception?

Comment: Is it erroring because you are trying to enter the same KindID?  It doesn't appear that the Name needs to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have the check if the `Kind` already exists in the DB. If yes, replace the kind in the `movie.Kinds` collection by the kind loaded from the database. If no, keep the deserialized kind and create a new `Kind` entity, for example like so:

```
using(Stream stream = myExternalStream)
{
    Movie movie = Unserialize(stream);
    var newKindList = new List<Kind>();
    foreach(var kind in movie.Kinds)
    {
        var kindInDB = _context.Kinds
            .SingleOrDefault(k => k.KindId == kind.KindId);
        if (kindInDB != null)
            newKindList.Add(kindInDB);
        else
            newKindList.Add(kind);
    }
    movie.Kinds = newKindList;
    _context.AddToMovies(movie);
}
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the movie kind, in stead of creating it each time. Or is that to obvious?

Comment: Yes because done automatically when deserializing and some can exists, some not

Comment: Aha, so the answer actually was try retreiving and only creating when it doesn't. That actually what my comment meant.